# Firebug doesn't load jQuery templates

Tags: jquery, firebug, jquery-templates

First off I need to change my script tag from "text/html" to "text/javascript" to be able to load the scripts with firebug. Now Firebug gives me the error message: XML can't be the whole program. My template looks like this:

```
     <script id="preview" type="text/javascript">
          <div style="width:${Width};height:${Height}" class='brick'>
            <img src="${Image}" width="${Width}" height="${Height}"/>
         </div>
     </script>
```

But I don' want to change my script tag to "text/javascript"?

Comment: But the script tag already *is* `"text/javascript"`. That ain't JavaScript in that JavaScript tag, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $.tmpl() plugin requires inline templates to have the type `text/x-jquery-tmpl` like this:

```
<script id="preview" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <div style="width:${Width};height:${Height}" class='brick'>
        <img src="${Image}" width="${Width}" height="${Height}"/>
     </div>
</script>
```

That should fix your issue; I hope this helps!